# unable to understand shared_pointer syntax

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

hi I just started with C++ and I am unable to understand the following syntax. Can someone please explain what is happening in this line? I expected a variable name but there isn't any.

```
std::shared_ptr<Some>(new Some())
```

I understand the following syntax

```
std::shared_ptr<Some> p = new Some()
```

but the first syntax is not very clear to me.

Comment: The first example looks incomplete.  You're initializing some object ... but I don't see where the object is being stored to any variable (where's "p"?).  I imagine most compilers would simply optimize the line away...

Comment: It creates a temporary shared_ptr. Unless you assign it to something, it dies immediately (at the end of the line), deallocating the memory.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, prefer using `std::make_shared` instead of `new`. It's harder to make a mistake and leak memory this way.

Comment: @paulsm4 If the asker meant that to be a full expression statement, rather than just a subexpression (no semicolon), then `Some`'s constructor(s) and destructor could still have side-effects, so it cannot necessarily be optimized away.

Comment: @user17732522 you're thinking of `std::make_unique`, `std::make_shared` did show up in C++11.

Comment: @Quentin Oh wow, I didn't remember that.

Comment: Don't you mean `std::shared_ptr<Some> p(new Some());`?

Comment: Please don't edit answers into your question, it's very confusing

Answer (score 4):

The following is a statement that initializes the variable `p`:

```
std::shared_ptr<Some> p = new Some();
```

The `shared_ptr` constructor will take the `Some*` returned by `new` and wrap it up in a `shared_ptr<Some>` object called `p`.

The following is not a complete statement, but an expression (a thing that evaluates to a value).  It evaluates to a value of type `std::shared_ptr<Some>` that "owns" a new `Some` object:

```
std::shared_ptr<Some>(new Some());
```

You can combine the two into a statement that is largely equivalent to the first statement above:

```
std::shared_ptr<Some> p = std::shared_ptr<Some>(new Some());
```

So, if you have a function that accepts a `std::shared_ptr<Some>` you could pass it an expression that created one:

```
void SomeFunction(std::shared_ptr<Some> obj);

...
  SomeFunction(std::shared_ptr<Some>(new Some));
```

This is the same syntax as `int(5)` or `MyClass(42)` -- those create `int` or `MyClass` objects, passing the arguments to their constructor.

Note that you probably don't want to use code like any of the examples above.  Try to avoid using `new`, especially when using smart pointers like `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`.  To create a `shared_ptr`, use `std::make_shared` instead.  An expression that creates a `shared_ptr` holding a `Some` object looks like this:

```
std::make_shared<Some>()
```

To assign that to a variable:

```
std::shared_ptr<Some> var = std::make_shared<Some>();
```

...but since that is repetitive, you can also use `auto`:

```
auto var = std::make_shared<Some>();
```

(there is also `std::make_unique<T>(...)` for creating unique pointers)

Or, if you want to call the `SomeFunction` I declared above with a new `Some` object:

```
  SomeFunction(std::make_shared<Some>());
```

...which as I'm saying is considered better style than this:

```
  SomeFunction(std::shared_ptr<Some>(new Some));
```

...even though both will compile and seem to run correctly, there is still a tiny bit of time where the `new Some` expression has created a `Some*` in an un-owned raw pointer, which can be error prone (especially if an exception is thrown).

To use `std::make_shared` you need to be using at least C++11.  To use `std::make_unique` you need to be using at least C++14.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that example. I'm so used to not writing code using `new` that I rarely ever run into this case. :-)